# ExpressJS routes how use and get differ

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a ExpressJS site, my first one and I'm having trouble getting routes working.

I have a app.js file that sets out the routes like this:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/work', work);
```

Then in my hjs layout page (I'm using Hogan as I don't like Jade) I have a link like this:

```
 <nav>
    <ul class="pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/users">Mobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

As you can see they are just simple href tags point to each route.

Now my Work link doesn't work, I get a 404 error I was wondering if there is more to setting up routes like this in a ExpressJS site. Or am I trying to build a Express site like I would a static site.

In the examples I've looked a lot of them have routes that show res.send() displaying text in the page or console, but nothing showing how to load a new view/html page.

Am I setting up the app.use wrong?

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

You should remove hashtag signs because this will not request a new page from your Server.

Comment: Cool, but I don't think that is the cause of why my new views don't load.

Comment: So you still get 404 response? You need to check your error log.